# ImageView под TextVew

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Каким образом сделать так чтобы картинка располагалась прямо под текстом и по центру, а не вверху экрана. Создал `ScrollView` файл,в  нем `RelativeLayout`, в котором есть `textview` и `imageview`. Вот их параметры:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="45px"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"/>  />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/foto2"
    android:src="@mipmap/foto"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:scaleType="center"/>
```

А вот java-код:

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
text.setText("какой-то текст");
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto2);
imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.foto);
```

Что нужно дописать, чтобы картинка следовала строго за текстом и не наползала на него, т.е чтобы сначала шел `TextView` потом по центру ниже располагалась картинка, а еще ниже возможно шел другой текст?

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать `CompoundDrawable`, убрав `ImageView` и добавив `android:drawableBottom="@drawable/myImg"` в `TextView`. Единственное, что нужно учитывать - у них будет одни LayoutParams на двоих.

можно задать такое поведение программно, через `textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);`

Answer (score 0):

Замените `RelativeLayout` на `LinearLayout`

Answer (score -1):

Поменяй местами text view и imageview, так картинка будет под текстом